# Testflight: Cannot upload build, cannot download SDK

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm having difficulties with TestFlight today. I've tried to upload ipa for the new app but getting this error:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting any new builds that use the TestFlight SDK. Please remove the SDK and re-upload. Learn More.

Learn more just point to generic Help portal, not helpful. Thought the problem is with actual SDK (it's not latest version) but when I went to Dashboard/SDK, there is another error waiting for me:

> Sorry, the TestFlight SDK is no longer available for download for Team xxx.
>   If you require technical support, please contact support@testflightapp.com

I've checked and I can only download SDK for one team, the rest of the teams is getting the same error.

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing this too. You can still distribute builds to testers though. Just remove the test flight SDK. Obviously you lose all the SKD features, but at least you can distribute.

Comment: Forget TestFlight: Apple has actually acquired TestFlight in Q4 2011

Comment: i am also getting same message from last couple of days : Sorry, the TestFlight SDK is no longer available for download for Team mygame.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is related to the [Apple purchase of TestFlight](http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/21/rumor-testflight-owner-burstly-is-being-acquired-by-apple/).

My colleague told me that Android has also been disabled for TestFlight so it wouldn't surprise me if they have taken the whole thing down for maintenance (updating/permanently/moving it to ITC/etc...).

Comment: Ah, that's news for me. Very bad news indeed. I guess it's start to look for replacement. Any tips maybe? Thanks for the update anyway!

Comment: They both seem to have similar features to TestFlight but none of them is free unfortunately (well, ubertesters is for 1-2 apps)

Comment: There are some similar issues http://blog.syncopelabs.co.uk/2014/02/testflight-is-no-longer-accepting-build.html

Comment: TestFlight is doing everything required. They do have automated uploads using CLI also.

Comment: I've also found [DeployGate](http://deploygate.com). Not free either (though might be if you sign up for iOS beta testing) but seems to be quite easy to use with quite a lot of features.

Answer (score 10):

According to [TestFlight](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1452760), this is because:

> On 2/19/2014 we announced that only Teams who have previously uploaded
>   a build with the TestFlight SDK will be able to continue to upload
>   builds with the SDK.

And this means that:

> - If your team has never uploaded a build with an
>     SDK or you are a new TestFlight user then you will not be able to
>     incorporate any version of the TestFlight SDK.

Comment: For further information
[Testflight link](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1452760)