# Any alternatives for TestFlight Crash Reports except TestFlight sdk?

Tags: ios, testing, testflight

As per the discussion in the below we can't integrate Testflight SDK. Then how can we track the crash reports via Testflight? Is there any alternatives?

[Testflight: Cannot upload build, cannot download SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983097/testflight-cannot-upload-build-cannot-download-sdk)
[TestFlight does not accept builds with TestFlight SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222643/testflight-does-not-accept-builds-with-testflight-sdk)

Comment: Try to use BugSense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

[Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/)

[HokeyKit](http://hockeykit.net/)

and Many more: [alternatives for testflight](http://venturebeat.com/2014/03/01/7-alternatives-to-testflight/)

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative is to use a log management tool that has crash reporting in it.

The logs help to identify the reason for the crash. See an article that I wrote in this subject: [Is A Crash Reporting Tool enough? Do I also need a Log Management tool?](https://www.shipbook.io/blog/crash-reporting-vs-log-management-tool)